How to disable the Microsoft Teams sidepane in Microsoft Edge when clicking a link in Microsoft Teams
Every time I click on a link in Microsoft Teams to open it in Microsoft Edge, I get some kind of tab on the right side of the browser asking me to sign into Teams. How can I disable that? I don't want to use Microsoft Teams in the browser. The tab that opens automatically looks like this:

I tried various solutions from here, however none of them worked. I don't have any Teams app installed, the sidepane settings look like this:

There also aren't any "three dots" on the side pane where I could deactivate anything.

Unfortunately, Microsoft changed this in modern versions of Teams. It no longer appears to be possible to hide the sidebar if it's on. The sidebar automatically hide when you open certain panes like Calendar, but it's not possible to hide it in other panes like Chat.

That's unfortunate and annoying.
